# url of navigations of jekyll posts do not work when pushed to github

Tags: url, jekyll, github-pages

I wanted to add the navigation capability to my blog posts on github pages.

I added the following code into my post.html:

```
<div class="PageNavigation">
  {% if page.previous.url %}
    <a class="prev" href="{{page.previous.url}}">&laquo;
        {{page.previous.title}}</a>
  {% endif %}
  ...
</div>
```

When I push the posts to github, the link will not work due to the fact that code is residing under a repository url. 
As a workaround, I added the repo name manually to the link. It becomes:

```
 <a class="prev" href="/myRepoName{{page.previous.url}}">&laquo;
        {{page.previous.title}}</a>
```

Now the problem is that the navigation is not working locally. Is there a simple solution to avoid this mess?

Comment: You could try setting a "Base URL". Locally you can override it with CLI options or by using several environments. See: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/ Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Christian! Indeed setting a base url did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **_config.yml** :

```
baseurl: /myRepoName
```

Link looks like :

```
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.previous.url }}" class="prev">
  {{page.previous.title}}
</a>
```